# Building VTK Examples on Ubuntu

Tags: vtk

After Building vtk with Qt on Ubuntu 16.04 I tried to make a few examples.

Here is one of them:
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Qt/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt#CMakeLists.txt

After running CMake with no errors on configure or generation I try to make but it blows up with this:

> [100%] Linking CXX executable SideBySideRenderWindowsQt
>   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkLocalExample
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   CMakeFiles/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt.dir/build.make:278: recipe for target 'SideBySideRenderWindowsQt' failed
>   make[2]: *** [SideBySideRenderWindowsQt] Error 1
>   CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt.dir/all' failed
>   make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt.dir/all] Error 2
>   Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

What should I do?

Comment: install libvtk6

Comment: I installed libvtk6.2 but I'm getting the same problem.

Comment: did you make sure you target is pointing to the right path?